# Map controls issue Three.js

Tags: javascript, dictionary, three.js

I'm trying to replicate controls similar to this [example](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=cont#misc_controls_map) which has a link for the [code](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/misc_controls_map.html). However whenever I try to replicate it turns into something like [this](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=cont#misc_controls_orbit). There is barely any difference between the two, they both use orbitcontrols.js, but the example I want implements it like this : `import { MapControls } from './jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';` .... `controls = new MapControls( camera, renderer.domElement );`. However, whenever I use `import` it doesn't work and comes with the error "Cannot use import statement outside of module". I looked into it and it seems I cannot use this anymore and I don't know how to create this effect.

In my code I linked the orbitcontrols.js in the head and used `controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );` instead.

I don't know how to get map controls.

Comment: You definitely need to import MapControls instead of OrbitControls.
Make sure at the bottom of the OrbitControls.js file you're importing, it has the MapControls definition https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js#L1147
Are you using the most up-to-date version of Three?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. The reason you are getting this error is because you are not using a module script file, you can solve it two ways. 1) on your HTML, modify the script tag to `<script type="module" src="youfile.js"></script>`. 2) Include on your HTML a link to the [non-module version](https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js). Then `MapControls` will be accessible as `THREE.MapControls`.

Comment: @ScieCode It works now. Thank you so much!